# How to set focus on textfeild by pressing forward slash in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any idea on how to do I set my cursor focus on textfeild, the functionality is similar to the vuetify website when we visit vuetify website there is search feild which has a placeholder (Search "/" to focus) the same functionality I want to achieve it in my website.

I am using vuejs with vuetify.

Any help with example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- you can use [key modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)
- also set the config for "/"  `Vue.config.keyCodes.slash = 191`
- to know more about [keycodes in vue refer this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keyCodes)
- [refer this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-the-focus-to-html-form-element-using-javascript/) to set focus on input in simple vanilla JS
- also I got that "/" keycode from [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/)

---

or simply use this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input id="input1" v-on:keyup.191="inpFocus">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  name: "something",
  .
  .
  .
  methods: {
    inpFocus(){
      document.getElementById("input1").focus();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am using vuetify textfeild

Comment: edit that input with `<v-text-field label="Regular" id="input1" v-on:keyup.191="inpFocus" ></v-text-field>`

Comment: [How to Set Focus on an Input in Vue](https://michaelnthiessen.com/set-focus-on-input-vue/)

Comment: Key codes are deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode. Do not use 191 anymore.